# How to implement a many to many relationship in ASP.NET using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Basically I am trying to insert a `userId` value and a `RoleId` value in an intermediate table in SQL Server 2010. The problem is that the code is not reaching the table and it stays empty while, using breakpoints, I can see the values to allocate the role are correct. I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 as a school project where I am trying to give users roles for different privileges in the website.

The method to set the roles is in the business layer:

```
public void RegisterUser(CommonLayer.User User, string ConfirmPassword)
{
    CommonLayer.User Existing = this.GetUser(User.UserEmail);
    BuisnessLayer.Roles roles = new BuisnessLayer.Roles();

    if (Existing == null)
    {
        if (User.UserPassword.Equals(ConfirmPassword))
        {
            User.UserId = Guid.NewGuid();
            User.UserPassword = HashSHA512String(User.UserPassword, User.UserId.ToString());
            User.UserTypeId = (1);
            this.AddUser(User);
            roles.AddUserRole("USR",User.UserId);
        }
    }
}
```

`AddUserRole` seems to be the problem because it is not inserting in the table the method for `AddUserRole` in the business logic is:

```
public void AddUserRole(string RoleCode, Guid UserId)
{
    DataLayer.DARoles dar = new DataLayer.DARoles(this.entities);
    DataLayer.DAUsers dau = new DataLayer.DAUsers(this.entities);
    CommonLayer.User User = dau.GetUser(UserId);
    CommonLayer.Role Role = dar.GetRole(RoleCode);
    dar.AllocateUserRole(User, Role);
}
```

Here are the codes for `GetUser` and `GetRole` in the data layer:

```
public CommonLayer.User GetUser(Guid UserId)
{
    return this.Entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserId.Equals(UserId));
}

public CommonLayer.Role GetRole(string RoleCode)
{
    return this.Entities.Roles.SingleOrDefault(p => p.RoleId == RoleCode);
}
```

And, here is `AllocateUserRole` in the data layer:

```
public void AllocateUserRole(CommonLayer.User User, CommonLayer.Role Role)
{
    User.Roles.Add(Role);
    this.Entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

[image: The database tables all have correct data types]

[image]

Comment: You should have a look at sample code for Microsoft's Membership providers. The identifiers for both User and Role are GUIDs and the samples should give you some guidance on usable ways to implement your functions. The code you included is not very clear or incomplete, so you'll have to make more effort on your own.

Comment: So, does GetUser and GetRole find what you expect? Is the problem only in AllocateUserRole?

Comment: AllocateUSerRole seems to be the problem cause both GetUser and GetRole get the values from the database

Comment: I think you want a UserRole class, and User should have a collection of that.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 and 2016 in the pipeline - which one are you *really* using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing `RoleId` with `RoleCode`.

You send `RoleCode` to `GetRole` method :

```
public void AddUserRole(string RoleCode, Guid UserId)
{
        ...
        CommonLayer.Role Role = dar.GetRole(RoleCode);
        ...
}
```

However your `GetRole` method compares it with `RoleId`

```
public CommonLayer.Role GetRole(string RoleCode)
    {
        return this.Entities.Roles.SingleOrDefault(p => p.RoleId == RoleCode);
    }
```

UPDATE :

I realized that you forget to add your user to `DbContext` , which is `this.Entities` in your context.

```
public void AllocateUserRole(CommonLayer.User User, CommonLayer.Role Role)
{
        User.Roles.Add(Role); // this does nothing to your Database. 

        //You should use this to add user to your context ( db )            
        this.Entities.Users.Add(User); 

        // or this if you want to update your user in your context ( db ).
        this.Entities.Set<CommonLayer.User>().Attach(User);
        this.Entities.Entry(User).State = EntityState.Modified;

        this.Entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Basically its the same thing because in the database im saving roleID as varchar as in code for the role eg for user - "USR" as primary key

Comment: @Student  You were updating the User object which have no effect to your database. Please see the updated answer.